# Display adjacent data to largest value within range while including duplicates

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I'm attempting to grab each instance of the largest value within a range and display the five adjacent columns of data associated with each instance.

[Sample](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wuhdY.png)

I was able to grab the largest data using this:

```
=IFERROR(LARGE($A$3:$A$100,ROW(1:1)),"NONE")
```

Unfortunately, I'm unable to figure out how to grab the adjacent data associated with the next instance of the duplicate value.

Note:

- The archive table is in ascending order because that is the only way I can think of to ease copying and pasting the latest data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you do not want to use a sorted order, you can simply use this array formula at `H3` and then auto-fill it to `M8`:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX($A$3:$F$18,SMALL(IF($A$3:$A$18=MAX($A$3:$A$18),ROW($1:$16)),ROW(A1)),COLUMN(A1)),"NONE")
```

> This is an array formula and must be confirmed with Ctrl+Shift+Enter!

If you still have any questions, just ask ;)

**EDIT**:

The core is `IF($A$3:$A$18=MAX($A$3:$A$18),ROW($1:$16))` which returns an array of rows and `False` like `{FALSE,2,FALSE,FALSE,5,FALSE.....}`. Knowing that `SMALL` ignores `FALSE`, You get with `SMALL(...,1)` the first row with the max value. (this way `SMALL(...,2)` will output the second row .....).

Using `ROW(A1)` and `COLUMN(A1)` as non static ref, you get the `k` for our `SMALL` and the column for our `INDEX` :)

Comment: Thank you very much Dirk! This worked exactly as intended. If you don't mind, could you do a short explanation of how this works? I understand if this is asking a bit much. Thank you either way :)

Answer (score 0):

Step 1)

Take your large function and compare it to the max from your source range,  if it is less than max display none, if otherwise have it display the max.

Step 2)

Since your data is sorted in ascending order find the position in the range of the first instance of your maximum value.

```
=MATCH(MAX($A$3:$A$18),$A$3:$A$18,0)
```

We will use this to return the corresponding values in the adjacent columns by substituting it into an index formula for each column to be returned

```
=INDEX(B$3:B$18,MATCH(MAX($A$3:$A$18),$A$3:$A$18,0))
```

Place the above in I3 and copy it to right

Step 3)

Since your Data is sorted in order it means the next row down in column A of the max value will be still max value or end of the list.  There for match value need to be increased by 1 for each consecutive row and needs some error handling

So we can use our formula from row 3 and adjust it as follows:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(B$3:B$18,MATCH(MAX($A$3:$A$18),$A$3:$A$18,0)+1),"NONE")

OR

=IF(H4="NONE","NONE",INDEX(B$3:B$18,MATCH(MAX($A$3:$A$18),$A$3:$A$18,0)+1)
```

then change the +1 to a +2 then +3, etc  however since we don't know wow many times this process will complete we can use the row reference which you started with and change the formula as follows:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(B$3:B$18,MATCH(MAX($A$3:$A$18),$A$3:$A$18,0)+(row()-3)),"NONE")

OR

=IF(H4="NONE","NONE",INDEX(B$3:B$18,MATCH(MAX($A$3:$A$18),$A$3:$A$18,0)+(ROW()-ROW($A$3))))
```

the -3 being the hardcoded value for your first row of data which could also be changed to -ROW(A3) where A3 is a cell in the first row of your new table.

## ERROR CORRECTION

I was adding the row bump to the match portion inside the match formula.  This was a mistake.  adding the +1,+2 or whatever needs to be added to the results of the match formula but still within the index formula.  I have updated the formulas above to reflect this.

Comment: Hi, Ed. Thank you for the detailed explanation. Unfortunately, when copying the final formula down, values adjacent to the remaining instances of the MAX are not resolved. For example, if A18 = 661741, and the second instance of that has unique data adjacent, it results in the error message of "NONE." 

Simplified: If A18 = 661741 and B18 = Longroad, everything works. But if A17 = 661741 and B17 = Longroad, "NONE" is displayed.

Comment: bare with me as I retype the data in.  See Dirks solution below.  I am not personally a fan of ARRAY formulas, but they do have their time and place.  See if it works for you.  I personally hate editing them.

Comment: No problem! I appreciate the effort you put in thus far. Out of curiosity, why do you prefer to avoid ARRAY formulas? Is there a technical reason behind it?

Comment: no technical reason.  When you have an array formula covering more than one cell, you cant edit the formula like you would normally.  its the CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER combination that I find a pain.  If you need to stretch the array formula down you need to break it first and then rebuild it.  A single cell array formula is not as bad.  so in the end its personal preference.  I see where I made my mistake

Comment: Gotcha. Thanks again!